# Does the groupid in Java has an incidence on how the package can read from each other?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am doing a Spring Boot app with Gradle. It will be a http api.

I decided to split in two modules:

- (1) libs-api and
- (2) myapp-api

Under (1), I will have sub module like: (1a) core / (1b) security.

Under (2), I will have sub modules like (2a) general / (2b) user-services.

I want to know if the groupId of (2a) and (2b) are respectively under `org.myapp.general` and `org.myapp.userservices`. Does it change in any way how the class are imported if it would have  been respectively `org.myapp` and `org.myapp` as group id?

I am not sure if a class from `org.myapp.userservices` can import a class in `org.myapp.general` or even `org.myapp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupId of your artefacts doesn't have any correlation with the package names you use in Java. It's completely different things. You can have different names for your groupId and package, and it will be valid.

> I am not sure if a class from org.myapp.userservices can import a class in org.myapp.general or even org.myapp

If the only thing you do is defining the hierarchy of the modules the answer is no, they can't be imported. You should add a dependency in your 'userservices' module pointing to your 'general' module. Then you will be able to import classes from your general module (if they have a public [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of course).

Answer (score 1):

The group ID is only used by Gradle (and Maven), it does not matter for Java at all. What counts on Java level is just the package name used in the code.